# Failed to read body as a JSON Object on curl command

Tags: json, curl, pusher

I am testing out push notifications for iOS Development and am currently using Pusher. When I run this command in terminal

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json"     -H "Authorization: Bearer 7FF3763C208E26F2198CE44624E9486B1EC8B02A489DCF2F476FD511763887AE" -X POST 'https://d3ca6e4b-3222-49c9-8028-f9c2d28b3ad7.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/d3ca6e4b-3222-49c9-8028-f9c2d28b3ad7/publishes' -d@publish-body.json
```

It gives me this warning

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "publish-body.json", this makes an empty 
Warning: POST.
{"error":"Bad Request","description":"Failed to read body as a JSON 
object"}
```

Here is my JSON file

```
{
  "interests": [
    "Reminder"
  ],
  "apns": {
    "aps": {
      "alert": {
        "title": "Hello",
        "body": "Hello, world!"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried going to the Pusher API and all it told me is that the error is due to a bad request. Any ideas on how to fix this? This app is a gift for my girlfriend and I would love to have this working!

Comment: `Couldn't read data from file "publish-body.json"` - so maybe make sure the file is there on that path and readable?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when I put quotation marks on the integer type in the json file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35128476)